# Android| crash after getting all info from API

Tags: android, json, eclipse

My app crash just after getting all information from API, have no idea why, I guess it's something with the text changing but as I say, have no idea, this is my first attempt with API, so here is the code:
ofc there are lines before, I've tried to fix this problem but i'm stuck with it so i'll be glad to get some help :)

```
                jsonString = sb.toString();
                JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
                JSONObject jObject2 = jObject.getJSONObject("data");

                Log.v("data =>",jObject2.toString());
                comicsNameOutput(jObject2);

            }catch (ClientProtocolException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        return null;

    }


    //provide the "result" section
    protected void comicsNameOutput(JSONObject jObject2) {          

        try{

                JSONArray comicInfoObject = jObject2.getJSONArray("results");
                Log.v("results =>",comicInfoObject.toString());
                finalDataProvidor(comicInfoObject);

        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }               


    }
    //get final data about each comic book
    protected void finalDataProvidor(JSONArray comicInfoObject) {
        String[] dataAboutEachComic = {"id", "title", "issueNumber", "pageCount"};

        try{

            for(int i = 0; i < comicInfoObject.length(); i++){
                JSONObject dataPerComicObject = comicInfoObject.getJSONObject(i);
                result = result + dataAboutEachComic[i] + " : " + dataPerComicObject.getString(dataAboutEachComic[i]) + "\n";
                Log.v("finalResult =>",result.toString());

            }

        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid){

            TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            textView1.setText(this.result);

    }


}
```

logcat view the info I requested, but as I said, it's crashing after getting all the information from the API.
The error on logcat:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOfBoundsExecption: legnth=4; index =4 
>   thread exiting with uncaught execption

Comment: If its crashing, there must be some exception shown in logcat. even after getting data.

Comment: forgot adding them, i'll edit, those are the errores: thread exiting with uncaught execption and the caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOfBoundsExecption: legnth=4; index =4 @MysticMagic

Comment: Its ArrayIndexOutOfBounds. On which line?

Comment: It doesn't exists in the code, I guess it's part of java.lang.Exception @MysticMagic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had problem with the array, I've mistakenly used the wrong Array(used I, which was way bigger than what I needed.

```
for(int i = 0; i < comicInfoObject.length(); i++){
                JSONObject dataPerComicObject = comicInfoObject.getJSONObject(i);
                for(int k = 0; k < dataAboutEachComic.length; k++){
                result = result + dataAboutEachComic[k] + " : " + dataPerComicObject.getString(dataAboutEachComic[k]) + "\n";
                }
```